# React js-How to prevent page reload once click on the link. Right now the whole page is getting refresh on clicking the link

Tags: javascript, reactjs, hyperlink, reload, window.location

I have link in which is the invoice number so once i click on it,it should provide data of particular invoice number without reloading the page.[code]

Answer (score 3):

use components that are provided by the 'react-router-dom' package, instead of the anchor tag 'a', use 'Link' or 'NavLink' components
example :
from this => `<a href='#'>my-link></a>`
to this => `<Link to='#'>my-link></Link>`

for more information , checkout the official documentation https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/examples/basic

Answer (score 1):

Routing is normally handled by *the browser*, which sends HTTP requests when the URL changes.
Here it seems you want *your app* to handle URL changes, so that it displays content depending on the URL. This is called client-side routing, you can do it using:

- the [history API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API)
- a library, for example [react-router-dom](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router-dom)

Answer (score 1):

You could prevent the page from reloading by using `preventDefault` method in the event practice.

```
function onLinkClick(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   // further processing happens here
}

<a href="/my-invoice-link" onClick={onLinkClick} />
```

Answer (score 1):

Easy way to redirect another page without refreshing the page ...

`import React from 'react';`
`import { Link } from "react-router-dom";`

addpost is route name

`<ul>`
`<li><Link to="/addpost">AddPost</Link> </li>`
`</ul>`